# Find Members from Sri Lanka

Tags: discussion

I'm from Sri Lanka (Country). How can I find users of the QGIS website from my Country. I mean the users that ask questions and answering from Sri Lanka. How can I filter those people from "Users" Section.

Comment: This should probably be in the meta section.

Comment: @U2ros - You can use the "Flag" button to alert the mods. I did right after it appeared; just waiting for the mods to wake up now and move it over. ;-)

Comment: Right, i forgot :>

Answer (score 5):

Here is the link to a [QGIS user map](http://plugins.qgis.org/community-map/). Just zoom into the area of interest and click to see users of interest.

[image]

Also see a related question on the stats meta site about searching the SO data dump, [Is there a way to view users by city/country?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1408/1036), and using the [StackMaps web based map](http://johndbritton.com/stackmaps/). These aren't specifically QGIS users, but people who fill in info on their GIS stack exchange profile. Unfortunately it appears no users have listed a location within Sri Lanka as of this time.

[image]